# Under what circumstances do you get the `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am making an app to send the battery level of my Windows 8 Phone over the network asynchronously after some specific interval of times. I am using the `DispatcherTimer` for calling sending the battery level after some specific interval.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();      //Create the timer instance
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);          //Set the timer interval
        timer.Tick += SendAsyncRequest;                     //Call this procedure after the time ends

        timer.Start();
```

I want to send my the battery level using the POST request.

```
void SendAsyncRequest(object sender, object e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.2.17/android_connect/add_device.php");            
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(SendBatteryLevel), request);

    }
```

Now, the heart of the code where I code for sending the actual request (`SendBatteryLevel`) is as follows:

```
void SendBatteryLevel(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        using (Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
        {
            string username = "CoolSops";
            string deviceId = "WindowsPhone";
            string batteryLevel = Windows.Phone.Devices.Power.Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent.ToString();
            string post_param = "username=" + username + "&device_id=" + deviceId + "&battery_level=" + batteryLevel;
            try
            {
                byte[] requestBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_param);
                postStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
                SendingStatus.Text = "Battery data sent";
                postStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    ErrorStatus.Text = e.ToString();
                });                   
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.Source + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }           
    }
```

where `SendingStatus` and `ErrorStatus` are `TextBlock`s. When I execute this code I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. The details of the exception are as follows:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

I do not understand what I am trying to access in an unauthorized way. Can anybody tell why this is happening?

Note:
I noted an interesting thing while debugging the program. When the method `SendBatteryLevel` is called from the method `SendAsyncRequest`, after executing a few lines from the `SendBatteryLevel` the control goes back to `SendAsyncRequest`. I tried to figure out the exact number of lines after which the control goes back to `SendAsyncRequest` but it varies every time. So, the method `SendBatteryLevel` is called twice or sometimes thrice in this manner before the method is completely executed. May be this is what is causing the exception to occur.

Comment: Am I missing something or did you forget to describe the _unable to do so_ part of this?

Comment: I am unable to send the battery level over to my web app.

Comment: Yes, your question says that. But... can you elaborate on the specific issue you are encountering that makes you _unable to send the battery level_?

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not encountering any issue. I don't get any error or warning. However, after the data is sent, I should be getting the message from the message box (which I'm not getting). Also, when I send the data to my PHP code, it (the PHP code) is coded to store the post request's data in the database. But I don't see any data in the database.

Comment: Have you tried _debugging_ to see what's going on?

Comment: I am getting an `System.InvalidOperationException` on the line `request.ContentLength = post_param.Length;`

Comment: `WebRequest.Create("localhost/battery.php");` That cannot be right. "localhost" is your phone, not your computer. It's probably not the only issue though.

Comment: @KooKiz - I tried changing that to my computer's IP but that doesn't help ether. Do you know any way in which I can allow my Emulator can send the post request my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Working with the byte arrays can be done in a more simpler way.
It's also necessary to set the `ContentLength` before getting the response stream.

Try this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.2.17/android_connect/add_device.php");
request.Method = "POST";

string username = "CoolSops";
string deviceId = "WindowsPhone";
string batteryLevel = Windows.Phone.Devices.Power.Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent.ToString();
string post_param = "username=" + username + "&device_id=" + deviceId + "&battery_level=" + batteryLevel;

byte[] requestBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_param);

request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;

request.BeginGetRequestStream(
    result =>
    {
        using (var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
        {
            postStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
            postStream.Close();
        }

        request.BeginGetResponse(
            (response) =>
            {
                // Handle response here....
            },
            null);
    },
request);
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the following exceptions:

`The thread 0xf34 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set all necessary capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml?

It looks to me that you've forgot to enable ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE, ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER or ID_CAP_NETWORKING.

Where do you get the exception? Can you get the Battery state or not?

Comment: I set all the capabilities. I'm getting the battery level. I'm not able to send it on the network.